# Python flask form gives 405

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have this form and every time I try to post it to the method in the buttom of the Question. The application just gives me a 405 error directly. I have checked that my database works by using the same method in the console.

(I have removed alot of html because it was just styling and stuff like that)

```
<form action="/register" method="post" class="grid">

                                    <div class="cell colspan3" style="margin-left:2%;">
                                        <div class="input-control modern text">
                                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
                                            <span class="label">Email</span>
                                            <span class="informer">Skriv din email</span>
                                            <span class="placeholder">Email</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cell colspan3">
                                        <div class="input-control modern text cell">
                                            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" >
                                            <span class="label">Brugernavn</span>
                                            <span class="informer">Skriv dit brugernavn</span>
                                            <span class="placeholder">Brugernavn</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cell colspan3">
                                        <div class="input-control modern text cell">
                                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                                            <span class="label">Password</span>
                                            <span class="informer">Skriv dit password</span>
                                            <span class="placeholder">Password</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cell colspan3">
                                        <div class="input-control modern text cell">
                                            <input type="password" name="passwordconfirm" id="passwordconfirm">
                                            <span class="label">Gentag password</span>
                                            <span class="informer">Skriv dit password igen.</span>
                                            <span class="placeholder">Gentag password</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="cell colspan3">
                                        <label class="input-control checkbox ">
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="accept_tos" id="accept_tos">
                                            <span class="check"></span>
                                            <span class="caption">Jeg accepterer hjemmesidens regler</span>
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cell colspan3">
                                        <div class="input-control cell">
                                            <button class="button success" type="submit">Registrer</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

            </form>
```

The python method that I call with my html post form:

```
 @app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        newUser = User(form.username.data, form.email.data, form.password.data)
        db.session.add(newUser)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        return render_template('register.html')
```

And the RegistrationForm method looks like this:

```
class RegistrationForm(Form):
    username = StringField('username', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    email = StringField('email', [validators.email, validators.Length(min=4, max=40)])
    password = PasswordField('password',
                             [validators.Required(),
                              validators.EqualTo('confirm', message='Passwords skal matche hinanden.')
                              ])
    confirm = PasswordField('passwordconfirm')
    accept_tos = BooleanField('Jeg accepterer regler for denne hjemmeside', [validators.Required()])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obviously there'snt any problem in these codes unless you have url_prefix for your current app like :

```
app = Blueprint('user', __name__, url_prefix='/user/')
```

and u have another blueprint with url_prefix like :

```
app = Blueprint('general', __name__, url_prefix='/')
```

with another funtion like :

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET'])
```

in the blueprint ...

and your form is posting data to '/register' instead of '/user/register'

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
```

to

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
```

Answer (score 0):

If that really is the code you're using, I can't see why you're getting a `405 Unsupported Method` rather than a validation error.  You need to render the hidden CSRF field in the html form.

```
<form ...>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
```

---

There are other things wrong with this code.  Redirect to login, don't render the template from the register view.  Use `form.validate_on_submit()`.  Don't pass `request.form` to the form.  Let the form render the inputs, don't write the html yourself.